# How to connect a webdriver script to an already opened chrome tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

i'm using webDriver with javaScript to automate exporting data from a website. The script needs to run in an already open window to avoid the login screen appearing.

a lot of the documentation is in Java so I haven't found anything specific to Javascript. Searched through webdriver.io and Selenium.dev with no luck

Answer (score 0):

That's where the args `--user-data-dir` and `--profile-directory` come into play. These let you specify an existing user data dir and profile directory to use when launching Chrome. That means your login cookies from your original Chrome window will carry over to your new Chrome window that's launched from webdriver.

Here's how the options would be set using Node/JS:

```js
const options = new chrome.Options();
options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=DIR");
options.addArguments("--profile-directory=DIR");
const driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser("chrome").setChromeOptions(options).build();
```

Comment: OP is looking for _Javascript_ based solution but not _Python_.